# Today widget UI not responding after updating height

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, today-extension

I am developing a Today widget with dynamic height. As a result of a `tapGesture` I am increasing the widget height using the method:

```
- (void)updateWidgetHeightWithSize:(TCWidgetSize)size {

  self.widgetSize = size;
  CGFloat height = 100;

  if (self.widgetSize == TCWidgetSizeLarge) {
    height = 200;
  }

  CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
  viewFrame.size.height = height;
  self.view.frame = viewFrame;

  [self setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height)];
}
```

But after setting the height back to 100, `UIButton` and `TapGesture` on the widget are not responding. If I close the `NotificationCenter` and open it again everything works properly. Please help..

Comment: Having the same issue in iOS 9.1, it just won't respond to taps.